# You know how many they/there are?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

Two people are talking about some hostage-takers. One of them asks the other:

"You know how many **they** are?"

Is it possible to say "they" here? Or should it be:

"You know how many there are?"

Or

"You know how many hostage-takers there are?"

?

Comment: There are five. Now, you write the question.

Comment: You can say "they are".

Comment: We are legion = we are many.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Not really: "They are five hostage takers" is not proper English. You either use There are/Are there, or write a different sentence...

Comment: How many in number are they? They are five (in number) is OK if somewhat old fashioned.

Comment: See here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377992/there-are-four-of-us-we-are-four-are-both-ways-correct - _From D. H. Lawrence's Quetzalcoatl - And, men, where we are ten they are a hundred. We send up one aeroplane, and they come down on us with a cloud of a thousand aeroplanes. – FumbleFingers Mar 11 '17 at 21:49_  and  _'Correct', but inherently ambiguous and of a literary style. – Edwin Ashworth Mar 11 '17 at 22:05_